# How can i remove default TITLE Bar in th android application?

Tags: android

Am new to this tech.
I am trying to build an application,in that i want to Remove default Title bar,and want to add my customised  title bar.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `ActionBar` in android. To remove it completely, you have to use a theme which doesn't contain `ActionBar` like `Theme.NoTitleBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` if you're using `AppCompat` support library.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom ActionBar to achieve this.
Please consider reading [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) and also [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)